# Azure Synapse Pipeline not detecting Notebook

Tags: azure-synapse

Azure Synapse Pipeline not detecting Notebooks. It was working well no and didnt make any changes. I cant even open notebook inside of pipeline like there setting and open sign + also open sign disappeared which is weird. Problem When i create new notebook cant select from list select notebook not available only dynamic is available. Can someone help with this issue?

I have tried to create new pipeline and added new notebook didnt work. I need to create to new notebook and select from the list.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CjNe.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced same scenario in my environment.

I am also having Some notebooks, but these notebooks are not available to select in dropdown list of pipeline activity synapse notebook

[image: demo]

To work around this first publish your notebook using `publish all`

[image]

Then go to your notebook there is one button Select the **Add to pipeline** button on the upper right corner to add a notebook to an existing pipeline or create a new pipeline as below:

[image]

It will load that particular notebook to that particular pipeline, and you can now run that notebook in pipeline

[image]

Answer (score -1):

that was a temporary bug in Synapse Studio. the issue has been fixed, so this shouldn't happen again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).